# React app needs two clicks to show updated state after axios put request

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, react-router, mern

I'm building a React app where I need to update a document in a MongoDB database when clicking a button. The update seems to work fine, but only after a second click on the button.

I set it up so that when I click a button, I call a function that makes an axios put request, then essentially redirects the user back to the same page to see the results. Before I redirect, I log the response from the put request. This log always seems to be one state behind the current state.

These buttons change colors based on this updated value in the document. The thing works, but it's always one step behind me!

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  Button,
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow
} from "@mui/material";
import { useNavigate, useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

const Game1 = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const players = useOutletContext();

  const updatePlayer = (status, id) => {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/players/${id}`, { game1: status })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        navigate('/status/game/1')
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  return (
    <Paper
      style={{ padding: '1em' }}
      elevation={ 2 }
    >
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>PLAYER NAME</TableCell>
            <TableCell>PLAYING</TableCell>
            <TableCell>NOT PLAYING</TableCell>
            <TableCell>UNDECIDED</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {
            players &&
            players.map(player => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={ player._id }>
                  <TableCell>
                    { player.fullName.toUpperCase() }
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      size="small"
                      color={
                        player.game1 === 'Playing' ?
                        'success': 'primary'
                      }
                      onClick={ () => updatePlayer('Playing', player._id) }
                    >
                      Playing
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      size="small"
                      color={
                        player.game1 === 'Not Playing' ?
                        'error': 'primary'
                      }
                      onClick={ () => updatePlayer('Not Playing', player._id) }
                    >
                      Not Playing
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      size="small"
                      color={
                        player.game1 === 'Undecided' ?
                        'warning': 'primary'
                      }
                      onClick={ () => updatePlayer('Undecided', player._id) }
                    >
                      Undecided
                    </Button>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              )
            })
          }
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  )
}

export default Game1;
```

This is driving me crazy! Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: which component of `/status/game/1` router?

Comment: Your API, is returning the old document from MongoDB, rather than the updated one.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, I had the same thought, but I double-checked. I'm using the new: true option.

Comment: What is the component you are navigating to that you are expecting to see any updated values of? It sounds like you say you navigate to the route already rendering this `Game1` component. What, or where, is the `players` array being updated to see any updates? The question needs more context.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I'm navigating to the same component. The players array is in the parent component.

Comment: Please try to edit question to include all relevant code you are working with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

everything seems to be right, have you tried to use async/await in updatePlayer function
or maybe add type="button" to your Button props

I'm not sure they would solve your problem but if you could fix it please let me know

Comment: Using async/await did the trick! Why would that make a difference?

Comment: I don't actually know, the way that you used Axios seems to be right too but I don't understand why that's not working as expected

Comment: I agree. It's not clear why mixing `async/await` with a Promise chain, often considered anti-pattern, would resolve anything here.